# Execution of Lua garbage collection causes C stack overflow

Tags: c, lua, stack-overflow

I am running Lua in microcontroller environment, using an RTOS.
The available resources are very limited (only a few kb of RAM), and I am trying to make sure that Lua will work correctly in this environment.

To stress test the whole firmware, and ensure that memory is handled correctly, I loaded a script that essentially does the following:

```
index = 1
data = {}

-- This function is called repeatedly, till memory exhaustion.
function test()
    data[index] = 5
    data[index + 1] = 6
    data[index + 2] = 7
    index = index + 3
end
```

What I expect from this function is to make Lua run out of memory (**heap** memory, due to the continuous allocations).

To my surprise the program failed in another way.
As the memory usage is increased, Lua calls the garbage collector to free up some memory. Each time the garbage collector is running, it is using more and more stack, leading to stack overflow long before the heap is exhausted. It seems that no matter how much I increase the stack size, the garbage collector will eat it all very soon.

*Note that I am talking here about the C runtime stack, the actual memory that the CPU accesses on the hardware, not the Lua API stack.*

Is this the expected behavior? I would expect that as the garbage collector has specific work to do, it should consume the same memory for every execution.

Is there any way to handle garbage collections to improve this situation?

Comment: Have you set `LUAI_MAXCCALLS` according to stack size on your system?

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff no. Can you elaborate on this? Will this solve also the GC overflow? Any ways to profile my application to find the correct limit?

Comment: It's your responsibility when building Lua to set `LUAI_MAXCCALLS` to sane value.  This constant is used by Lua to raise "C stack overflow exception" when number of nested C calls exceeds this constant.  This is the only stack overflow protection in Lua.  It has nothing to do with GC.

Comment: Understood. By my problem is specifically with the way that GC works. These routines cause the stack overflow, not the execution of the script itself.

Comment: do you repeatedly execute whole script, or only test function?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. The test function is called repeatedly till there is a memory exhaustion (or in my case, stack overflow).

Comment: Using the code you provide and `while(1) do test() end` i get a `not enough memory` error. did this on 5.1, 5.2, and 5.3. What flavor of lua are you using? eLua?

Comment: Just to expand on what @Nifm asked, if you run `while(true) do test() collectgarbage() end` do you still run out of stack? If not you might need to set the gc to be more aggressive.

Comment: @Nifim I am using plain Lua 5.2.2. Not eLua. I have quite limited stack memory on my device, so it may be possible that on a desktop PC it is not reproducible.

Comment: @PaulR I also tried your recommendation, but the problem persists.